# Is there a generic way of passing a DbType as a parameter

Tags: c#, .net, sql, idbconnection

I need to execute this parameterized query, or an equivalent:

`ALTER TABLE tableName ADD COLUMN ? ?`

with the parameters as the name of the new column, and the data type.
For example, if I pass in 'Name' DbType.Double, then it would resolve to:

`ALTER TABLE tablename ADD COLUMN Name FLOAT`

I can't just create a mapping between DbType and the name of the field type, as the code's working on the `IDbConnection` interface, not a specific implementation. Is there a generic way of doing this? Right now I've got a separate mapping for each implementation, which is obviously far from ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to do this dynamically, and it may make sense to look at a provider-specific translation (so providers can supply their own mappings).